# Quantum mechanics calculations - must they always output a rational number?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, probability, mathematics, discrete

If space is quantized, and particles are quantized, then the chance of a particle showing up in a specific unit of space must be a rational fraction?

Could a quantum mechanics calculation ever output a percentage likelihood that is an irrational number? For example, could it state that the chance of an electron showing up in a certain location is $1/\sqrt{2}$, or $1/\pi$?

Or does it always have to be a rational fraction?

Comment: Why do you think it has to be a rational number?

Comment: If space is quantized, and particles are quantized, then the chance of a particle showing up in a specific unit of space must be a rational fraction?

Comment: ok, that's a reasonable conjecture.

Comment: Check this out and related work: https://arxiv.org/abs/0711.4863

Comment: "If space is quantized," there is no evidence that it is. Quantization in any case does not mean that a continuum does not exist, only that under certain boundary conditions energy levels are quantized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no reason why a probability couldn't be an irrational number.

[The Born rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Born_rule) states that it the probability of measuring a given eigenvalue $\lambda_{i}$ when applying an operator $A$ will equal $\langle \psi |P_{i}|\psi \rangle $, where $P_{i}$ is the projection onto the eigenspace of $A$ corresponding to the eigenvalue. There is no rule preventing $P_i$ from being full of irrational numbers.

For example, if we look for the position of a particle in a infinite square potential well $[0,a]$ the position wavefunction inside is $\psi_n(x,t)=\sqrt{2/a} \sin(\frac{n\pi}{a}x)e^{-iE_n t/\hbar}$ and the probability of finding a particle at location $x$ is $|\psi(x)|^2=(2/a)\sin^2(\frac{n\pi}{a}x)$. If we take $n=1$, $a=\pi$ and select (say) $x=1$ then the probability density is $(2/\pi)\sin^2(1)$ where both terms are irrational ([proof for the sine term](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1124435/proving-that-sin1-radian-is-irrational-without-using-taylor-series-expansio), the first one follows from irrationality of $\pi$); I am not 100% sure I can prove their product is irrational, but it is obviously not hard to nudge $x$ to give an irrational number.

Comment: Is it a valid assumption that you could take a=π, or any other irrational value? Aren't we constrained by quantization to only use rational values as inputs?

Comment: @Paul Quantum mechanics doesn't quantise space in the sense of giving it a discrete lattice-points structure. Even string theory doesn't *really* do that. Loop quantum gravity sort-of does, but that would be a simplification. What QM does is to impose $[x_i,\,p_j]=i\hbar\delta_{ij}$.

Comment: Well, try $a=1$ and plug in $x=1/10$, and you get $2\sin^2(\pi/10)=(1/4)(3-\sqrt{5})$.

Comment: Upon further reading, it looks like my question was really more general than quantum phyisics, and was indirectly answered on the math forum - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42231/obtaining-irrational-probabilities-from-fair-coins#42233

Answer (score 4):

Not only is there no particular reason to believe that space is quantized, but even if it were your conclusion does not follow from your premises.

Why?

Because the time dependent Schrödinger equation described a *continuous* evolution in time, and the rational numbers simple aren't continuous.

Of course, you could try adding discrete time (another thing for which there is no particular evidence) to your list of premises requiring you to convert the TDSE to a difference equation of some kind, but you would still have to deal with potentials that are non-linear (and indeed non-polynomial) functions of spacial separation<sup>1</sup> and you *still* wouldn't be able to guarantee rational probabilities.

---

<sup>1</sup> Keep in mind here that space is multi-dimensional so the distance can be irrational even if position is gridded. Just consider the distance between (0,0) and (1,1).

Comment: Or in other words, assuming that space is quantized does not tell you anything about probabilities because space and probabilities are completely different things. And assuming that space is quantized takes you strictly outside of Known Physics to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

As @AndersSandberg elaborated, probability calculations frequently result in irrational numbers. And that's not only for observables with a continuous spectrum of possible outcomes. Even a spin-up/down measurement can have an irrational probability of a spin-up outcome when the measured particle is initially prepared spin-up, but the subsequent detector axis is rotated through an angle whose cosine is irrational (which would be most angles).

But I'm reading/interpreting your question more operationally. Clearly, if you perform such spin measurements, you can only repeat them a finite number of times, say $N$, resulting in $n_{\mbox{up}}$ spin-up outcomes, whereby $n_{\mbox{up}}/N$ is obviously always rational.

More generally than above, there's been somewhat of an ongoing debate about whether or not natural laws themselves (beyond just repeating measurements $N$ times) are necessarily computable, e.g., https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9706006 and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church%E2%80%93Turing%E2%80%93Deutsch_principle and https://www.cs.ucsb.edu/news/events/physics-computable and lots more if you google "physics and computability".

In this case the upshot would be that outcome probabilities would necessarily be computable reals. While these can certainly be irrational (e.g., $\pi$ and $e$), there are only a countable number of computable reals which, like the rationals, can be enumerated.